# Mysql: bulk delete images from posts while still using their thumbnails

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

I am new in MySQL.
I would like to delete all the images that were uploaded to posts and pages of a Wordpress site, while still using them as attachments/thumbnails (as featured images). 
That is why, I can’t bulk delete them from the media library, only from within posts and pages. 
Since it’s a huge amount of images, I’d prefer using mysql command. 
The string of the images is always written as follows - `<img xxxx>`, where xxx is varied based on the img location and other details such as alt, width and height etc. 
The table is `wp_posts` and the fieldname is `post_conten`t 
The closest command I came across to is –

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<img%>', '')
WHERE post_content LIKE '<img%>';
```

It doesn’t work. 
Any clues?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the '<img' tag - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WordPress database structures, and can't figure out exactly what you mean, but don't you just mean this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = '' WHERE post_content LIKE '<img%';
```

This will delete everything from the post_content column that starts with '< img'. Alternatively you can do NULL instead of ''.